# Double for loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I need to do an estimation procedure for `n` time series (`n` vectors of `T` observations). I have the formula to evaluate my variable (using a for loop) but I need to repeat this `n` times (the number of vectors).

```
h0 = var(residuals);
ht=zeros(T,n); ht(T,1)=h0;
for i=2:T
    ht(i) = theta(1) + theta(2)*residuals(i-1)^2 + theta(3)*ht(i-1);
end
```

So this loop calculates `ht` for all of the observations in series one, but I need another for loop that helps me to use this formula for all of the series.

---

**Edit:** This is what I've done based on the below answer:

```
function ht = VarEQ(theta,residuals)    
    [T,n] = size(residuals)
    for k=1:n
        h0 = var(residuals(:,k));
        ht=zeros(T,n); ht(1,k)=h0;    
        for i=2:T
            ht(i,k) = theta(1,k) + theta(2,k)*residuals(i-1,k)^2 + theta(3,k)*ht(i-1,k); 
        end  
    end
end
```

Current problem:
Now `ht` is all columns of zero and just the last column of correct values.

---

**Variables**

`var` is a 1xn row vector of variances. Using `k`, I want just the scalar for each residual.

`theta` is a 3xn matrix of parameters.

`residuals` is a Txn matrix.

Comment: Where does the `n` come in?

Comment: n and T are [T,n]=size(residuals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems simple given what you already have set up:

```
function ht = VarEQ(theta,residuals)    
    [T,n] = size(residuals)
    ht=zeros(T,n);  % Initialise matrix OUTSIDE loop so it isn't over-written! 
    for k=1:n       % additional loop for series 1 to n
        ht(1,k) = var(residuals(:,k));;    
        for i = 2:T
            % Ensure you are referencing the kth series
            ht(i,k) = theta(1,k) + theta(2,k)*residuals(i-1,k)^2 + theta(3,k)*ht(i-1,k); 
        end  
    end
end
```

**Note:** previously, all columns of `ht` were the same, because `theta` and `residuals` were the same for each series!

With your updated code, and the updated code in this answer, that has been fixed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include new code and information like that which is unclear in comments... We also need details about what data/sizes are for `var`, `residuals`, `theta` ...

Comment: Your `ht` is all zeros because you are defining it as all zeros every loop! Put `ht=zeros(T,n);` **before** the loop, as in my example above. See my edited answer.